# Div Tags overlapping in Jade

Tags: css, node.js, pug

```
Jade file
======
doctype html
html
  head
      title= title
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
      div(id="topBar")
          h1(id="title") title
          form(id ="loginForm",name="input", action="html_form_action.asp", method="get", align="right")
               table
                    tr
                      td
                        key(for = "username") Username
                      td
                        input(id="username",type="text", name="user")
                      td
                        key(for="password") Password
                      td
                        input(id="password",type="password", name="pswd")
               input(type="submit", value="Login")
       div(id="content")
           h1(id="slogan") Slogan
 CSS File
 =========

 body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

     }
 p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
   }
#topBar{
       top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: darkcyan;
     color: white;

     }
     #title{
         margin-bottom: 2%;
          margin-right: 2%;
           margin-left: 5%;
          margin-top: 2%;
            float: left;
         display: inline;
        }
    #loginForm {
        float: right;
       position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
      margin-right: 2%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-top: 2%;

      display: table;
      font-family: cursive;
   }
   #content{
       display: inline-block;
    }
     h1{

      font-family: cursive;
     }
   a {
   color: #00B7FF;
    }
```

Hey i am beginner to Jade and node js. I was trying to build a simple login page. But my div tags are overlapping please help.I tried overflow: hidden and other things but nothing is happening. I want place these two div tags vertically.

Comment: Who is forcing you to use jade? go with HTML to create things if jade is complicating things.

Comment: If you've got overlap, it's almost certainly an issue with the CSS. Indeed, I'm thinking the overlap issue would be fixed if you stripped out all the CSS (at least for the divs). Though I can't really make any suggestions for fixes without knowing what it *should* look like. An image of the basic design drawing or mockup of the intended look of web page would be helpful. Otherwise, I'd say remove all the lines with `display`, `float`, and `position` in the CSS would be a good start to fixing the issue.

Comment: I am having a similar issue without even applying any css to the divs. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. display: inline-block on the div which was being overlapped by the other solved my problem.